# React form, to submit object which is then pushed to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, reactjs, submit

I'm new to React and unsure about how to do this.

I have an array of objects that I have mapped through and rendered in my view. What I want to do is set up a form that will submit the values of each field to the corresponding properties of a new object, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

**Here is my initial data, which is rendered in the view:**

```
contactArray = [
  {
    name: 'John'
    email: 'john@email.com'
    number: 111-111-111
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave'
    email: 'dave@email.com'
    phone: '222-222-222'
  }
]
```

**Then I have a form:**

```
class InputForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (   
        <form>
          <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button type='submit' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    ) 
  }
```

**Then I assume I declare the state as this:**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  }
}
```

**Then the submission function I don't really know how to handle...**

```
handleSubmit() {
  // not sure about this...
  this.setState({
    name: // ????
    email: // ????
    phone: // ????
  })
}
```

And then I want to clear the submit form, as well as the object that is used to push the new object, which is now in the array (I hope that makes sense...)

So, I'm not even sure how to use state in this scenario, but ultimately I want to `push()` the new object to the array that is rendered, with all the properties as they were completed in the form.

Sorry I can't be more complete with my working up to this point, but would at least appreciate some pointers on this!

Comment: Please add the `update` section from your question as a comment on Pranesh's answer. Replies to answers should not be posted on the question itself but should be posted/discussed on the comment section of the respective answer(s) posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set `state` for all the `inputs`. If you do, it'll be a problem when you have more `input` fields. See the below fiddle, in that, I've used a single `state` to store the entire contacts. When you press the submit button, it get all the values from the `input` and save it to the `state`. Hope it helps!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/8u4uz5xj/1/

**[UPDATE]**

1. `e.value = null` will clear the value inside the form. By this, you'll able to reset the entire form.
2. `slice()` is used to make a copy of the array in the state. As assignment of array is a `reference` to the original array, any operation on the new array will also reflect in the original array.

Example:

```
a = [1,2,4]
b = a
b.push(7)
console.log(b) //prints [1,2,4,7]
console.log(a) //also prints [1,2,4,7]
```

But

```
b = a.slice() //creates a copy of a
b.push(7)
console.log(b) //prints [1,2,4,7]
console.log(a) //also prints [1,2,4]
```

More details about [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

By doing this, you'll not mutate the existing state, which is a good practice.

Hope it help!!

Comment: Thanks. Although the JSFiddle is more or less what I put in my OP... Did you send the wrong link?

Comment: @Paulos3000 Hey! Sorry! Updated the link.

Comment: Really helpful - thanks. Please take a look at my update, there's a couple of things I wasn't sure about in your code...

Comment: @Paulos3000 Added the explanations.

Comment: Thanks! That's cleared up both those issues. Although, I think you meant `.slice` not `.splice`... FYI. `.splice` clears the original array when `handleSubmit()` is executed.

Comment: Just a note - an alternative way to clear the form elements after submission is to call `.reset()` on the form element on submission. I just found that out and thought it might be useful for anyone facing this scenario...

Comment: @Paulos3000 That's helps! Thanks!

Comment: fiddles broke can you share another example in fiddle

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand you want to push new people to the existing `contactArray` ? I will share with my way of doing it. Have a look:

```
const contactArray = [
{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    phone: '111-111-111'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    email: 'dave@email.com',
    phone: '222-222-222'
  }
];

class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      contacts: contactArray
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const
    { contacts } = this.state,
    name = this.refs.name.value,
    email = this.refs.email.value,
    phone = this.refs.phone.value;
    this.setState({
      contacts: [...contacts, {
        name,
        email,
        phone
      }]
    }, () => {
      this.refs.name.value = '';
      this.refs.email.value = '';
      this.refs.phone.value = '';
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { contacts } = this.state;
    console.log('message',this.state.contacts);
    return (   
      <div>
        <h2>Add Someone</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="name" />
          <input type="text" ref="email" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="text" ref="phone" placeholder="phone" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2>Exsiting contacts:</h2>
        <ul>
          {contacts.map((contact) => 
           <li>{`Name: ${contact.name} Email: ${contact.email} Phone: ${contact.phone}`}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So first thing we do is save `contactArray` within our actual component where we are going to use it, next we decalre and bind our `handleSubmit` I am using `refs` for the inputs in order to get thier value. `this.setState ({ contacts: [...contacts] , { Object });` Here we use the ES6 spread operator to pass all the existing contacts to our new state and add a new contact. `{ name, email, phone }` Is exactly like doing `{ name:name, email:email ...}` It's just a short-hand, `this.setState({}, () => { Callback! });` In the callback function of `this.setState({});` I am going to clear the input values. Live demo: http://codepen.io/ilanus/pen/qaXNmb

Here is another way you can do it, same results different approach.

```
const contactArray = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    phone: '111-111-111'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    email: 'dave@email.com',
    phone: '222-222-222'
  }
];

class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      contacts: contactArray,
      newContact: {
       name: '',
       email: '',
       phone: ''
     }
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { contacts, newContact } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      contacts: [...contacts, newContact],
    }, () => {
      for (let val in newContact) {
        newContact[val] = ''; // Clear the values...
      }
      this.setState({ newContact });
    });
  }

  handleInput(e, element) {
    const { newContact } = this.state;
    newContact[element] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ newContact });
  }

  render() {
    const { contacts, newContact } = this.state;
    const { name, email, phone } = newContact;
    return (   
      <div>
        <h2>Add Someone</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={name} onChange={e => this.handleInput(e, 'name')} placeholder="name" />
          <input type="text" value={email} onChange={e => this.handleInput(e, 'email')} placeholder="email" />
          <input type="text" value={phone} onChange={e => this.handleInput(e, 'phone')} placeholder="phone" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2>Exsiting contacts:</h2>
        <ul>
          {contacts.map((contact) => 
           <li>{`Name: ${contact.name} Email: ${contact.email} Phone: ${contact.phone}`}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live demo: http://codepen.io/ilanus/pen/LRjkgx

I highly recommend using the first example. as it's performance will be better :)

Comment: Thanks. I have read that you should avoid using refs where possible - I've never used them so am unsure of their limitations... can you clarify at all on this?

Comment: @Paulos3000 why not use refs? I have added another example of the form summation without refs too.

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly, I read it here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_refs.htm - I just wanted to better understand when they're appropriate rather than rely on them and later discover their drawbacks.

Comment: codepen broken do you have another example