# how can I store 4input data to an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

please help I don't understand how to store input data into an array
In my code I have 4 input field and I want to store there data into option array
Like -option: ["option1","option2","option3","option4"],
please help not understand what to do, its really confusing
(this is all rough {
qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm poiuytrewqasdfghjklmnbvcxz zxcvbnmlkjhgfdsaqwertyuiop
zxcvbnmlkjhgfdsaqwertyuiop mnbvcxzasdfghjklpoiuytrewq mnvxzasdfghjklpoiuytrew
mnbvcxzsdfghjklpoiuytrewq}
)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import { isAutheticated } from "../auth/helper/index";
import { createaPoll } from "./helper/adminapicall";

const AddPoll = () => {
  const { user, token } = isAutheticated();
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    question: "",
    option: [],
    error: "",
    loading: "false",
    getRedirect: false,
    formData: "",
  });

  const { question, option, error, loading, getRedirect, formData } = value;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // setError("");
    setValue({ ...value, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="AddPoll">
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Add New Poll</h1>
        <form>
          <textarea
            rows="4"
            cols="50"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Question"
            name="question"
            value={question}
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            autoFocus
          ></textarea>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option1"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option"
            value={option}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option2"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option"
            value={option}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option3"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option"
            value={option}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="Option4"
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
            name="option"
            value={option}
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn Submitbtn">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddPoll;
```

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769513/react-form-to-submit-object-which-is-then-pushed-to-array

Answer (score 0):

Change your state to this :

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    question: "",
    option: {option1:"",option2:"",option3:"",option4:""},
    error: "",
    loading: "false",
    getRedirect: false,
    formData: "",
  });
```

Replace this on handleChange function.

```
const newOption = {...value.option, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
setValue(prev => ({ ...prev , option: newOption  }));
```

Also change your input value and name to this :

```
name="option1"
value={option.option1}
```

After all you should get something like this on your option state:

```
option:{option1 : "value",option2 : "value",...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code if you want to have array like options.

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let options = ...value.option;
    options.push(event.target.value);
    setValue({ ...value, option: options });
  };
```

Comment: His structure is a little messy, look at his input also.